Unable to make a custom Widget occupy space while native Widgets like Row, Text work fine
I want to make a static grid where each quadrant takes equal space.
When I use native widgets like Text or Row they work fine. But when I am using my own widget ( which is simple ) it doesn't work.
Using Custom Widget with UI

Using native widget with UI

Custom widget


Please mark the answer as Solved

You didn't apply the modifier
@Composable
fun Quadrant(
  modifier: Modifier,
) {
  Column(modifier) { // <-- here
  }
}


That works! Why is it needed though?

Well if you just define a function argument and never use it, it's useless, it can't do anything, even the IDE warns you that you probably forgot about it... If you look at all the composables like Column or Text, they all take the modifier argument they receive and pass it on until it eventually reaches the core Layout composable which actually uses the modifier... Hard to explain I guess, but it's like creating fun myOwnPrint(text: String) { print("") } and finding it weird it doesn't print anything :D.
